# Angular, Output decoration is not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, output, eventemitter

When using @output, the methods of my parent component are not executed.

Hello, I am trying to send an array and a number through EventEmitter but the methods of my parent component are not executed.

Parent component: monitoreo
Child component: tree-monitoreo

tree-monitoreo.component.html:

```
<div class="expandible" [style.margin-left.px]="(item.level === 2 ? 14 : item.level === 3 ? 43 : 0)">
    <span *ngIf="item.children" (click)="toggleExpand()">[{{ item.expanded ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="ActivarCheckBox(item.name)"> {{ item.name }}
</div>

<div *ngIf="item.expanded && item.children">
    <app-tree-monitoreo *ngFor="let child of item.children" [item]="child"></app-tree-monitoreo>
</div>
```

tree-monitoreo.component.ts:

```
export class TreeMonitoreoComponent {

  @Output() datos: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
  @Output() id = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Input() item:any;
  private checkboxPreviousState: boolean = false;

  busData = [
      { name: "Bus 1", longitude: -79.025062, latitude: -8.134483, nId: 1, msg: "msg1"},
      { name: "Bus 2", longitude: -79.039958, latitude: -8.111403, nId: 2, msg: "msg2"},
  ]

  toggleExpand() {
    console.log("entro a toggle expand");
    this.item.expanded = !this.item.expanded;
  }

  ActivarCheckBox(value: any) {
    console.log("in Activarcheckbox");
    if (!this.checkboxPreviousState) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.busData.length; i++) {
        let busData = this.busData[i];
        if(value == busData.name) {
          this.datos.emit([busData.latitude,busData.longitude,busData.nId,busData.msg]);
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.busData.length; i++) {
        let busData = this.busData[i];
        if(value == busData.name) {
          this.id.emit(busData.nId);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    this.checkboxPreviousState = !this.checkboxPreviousState;this.checkboxPreviousState;
  }
}
```

monitoreo.component.html:

```
<body>
     <div class="menu">
          <app-menu></app-menu>
     </div>
     <div class="nav-monitoring">
          <div class="resizable">
               <div class="tree-container">
                    <app-tree-monitoreo class="tree-item" 
                         *ngFor="let item of treeData"
                         (datos)="actualizarMapa($event)"
                         (id)="removerMarca($event)" 
                         [item]="item">
                    </app-tree-monitoreo>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="adjacent" id="map"></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

monitoreo.component.ts:

```
export class MonitoreoComponent implements OnInit {

  private map:any;
  private marker:any;
  private marcadores: { [key: string]: L.Marker } = {};

  treeData = [
    { name: 'Centro de monitoreo 1', level: 1, expanded: true, children: [
      { name: 'Bus 1', level: 2, expanded: true, children: [
        { name: 'Cam 1', level: 3 },
        { name: 'Cam 2', level: 3 },
        { name: 'Cam 3', level: 3 },]},]},
    { name: 'Centro de monitoreo 2', level: 1, expanded: true, children: [
      { name: 'Bus 2', level: 2, expanded: true, children: [
        { name: 'Cam 1', level: 3 }, 
        { name: 'Cam 2', level: 3 },
        { name: 'Cam 3', level: 3 },]},]},
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.map = this.inicializarMapa();
  }

  inicializarMapa() {
    this.map = L.map('map').setView([-8.134483, -79.025062], 13);
    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(this.map);
    return this.map;
  }

  actualizarMapa(datos:any[]) {
    console.log("in actualizarMapa");
    this.marker = L.marker([datos[0], datos[1]],{
      icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'assets/img/marker-icon-2x.png',
        shadowUrl: 'assets/img/marker-shadow.png',
        iconSize: [40, 40],
        iconAnchor: [20, 40],
        popupAnchor: [0, -40]
      })
    }).addTo(this.map).bindPopup(datos[3]).openPopup();
    
    this.marcadores[datos[2]] = this.marker;
  }

  removerMarca(nId:number) {
    console.log("in removerMarca")
    if (this.marcadores[nId]) {
      this.marcadores[nId].remove();
      delete this.marcadores[nId];
    } 
  }  

}
```

In the console I cannot see see that the actualizarMapa and removerMarca methods are executed. Help please.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you've got the child component embedded in itself?  I see "<app-tree-monitoreo.." in the child and parent.

Comment: Yes, in the child, it's an array to create a dropdown tree. Could that be causing the error where the parent's methods are not being called?

Comment: not sure... seems like that would be an infinite loop though.  Are you seeing any errors thrown? Anything nested inside of the first child would not bubble up to the parent.

Comment: It seems that was causing the error. The console wasn't throwing any errors, but I've removed that part of the code in the child and now the parent methods are responding. Thank you!